# What battery can I use for an old Canon Ex EE (PX625 vs PX625A)?

Tags: canon, exposure, battery, 35mm, old-cameras

I recently bought a Canon Ex EE (1967) but there isn't a battery.
I read from the manual that it used PX625(1.35V) but there isn't any available now.
I do not want to buy zinc-air cells.
There are PX 625A(1.5V) and LR44 also 1.5V available.
If I use these are they harmful to my camera, such as burning the circuit board?
If not then which one is better?

Comment: You might want to ask at [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com). Sounds like it would be right up their alley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's technical information [here](http://www.smallbattery.company.org.uk/sbc_px625.htm) about the various substitutes available that give you more options. The page lists several substitutes with information about availability as well as technical information regarding voltage stability.

Comment: Would you be able to summarise the contents of the link here? We generally frown on link-only answers. Thanks!

Comment: There's not much to summarise - the page lists several substitutes with availability and technical information regarding voltage stability.